# Real Tough: How to insert a single column into multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server-ce

```
OrderDate    Region  Rep     Item    Units   Unit        Cost  Total
01/06/10    Quebec  Joneson Pencil  95      1.990      189.05
01/23/10    Ontario Kiveell Binder  50      19.99      999.5
02/09/10    Ontario Jardine Pencil  36      4.990      179.64
02/26/10    Ontario Gillber Pencil  27      19.99      539.73
03/15/10    Alberta Sorvino Pencil  56      2.990      167.44
04/01/10    Quebec  Joneson Binder  60      4.990      299.4
04/18/10    Ontario Andrews Pencil  75      1.990      149.25
05/05/10    Ontario Jardine Pencil  90      4.990      449.1
05/22/10    Alberta Thompso Pencil  32      1.990      63.68
06/08/10    Quebec  Joneson Binder  60      8.990      539.4
```

This is the data I have... it's all imported to a single column rawdata `varchar(8000)`.. now I want to export this data to table with multiple columns as the column headers (`Orderdate`, `Region`, rep...).. but I can't.. help me out.. thanks in advance

Comment: You should read msdn: [string manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx). But you shouldn't have that kind of data in the first place, this is an obvious case of poor design.

Comment: what do u mean poor design?..I just want to import it to multiple coloumns and cast it, but the values like unit,unitcost can not be casted to int or money..due to extra spaces..i tried trimming it with ltrim(rtrim(substring(...)))..but it still throws an error.sayin can't covert char type to int. Help me out

Comment: By poor design, i mean that your real problem is the fact that you have an entire SQL table stored as varchar in the column of another table. That is plain stupid, whoever did this would have gotten fired where i work. The correct way would be to redo the import of data, this time straight to a more suitable table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to SQL and columns in particular, the golden rule is to store only atomic data per column.

Example: you don't store John Smith into a "Client" column. You store John into "ClientName" and Smith in "ClientFamilyName".
This allows you to make any combination of these values down the road.
You are currently breaking (for the lack of a stronger term) this rule.

You need to redo your import so that each column in the original source matches a column in your SQL database. You can then import the OrderDate as a proper datetime in sql, the units as int, region as varchar, etc.